# What is the difference between a temporary variable and a local variable in C?

Tags: c, local-variables

In C, a function that returns a value is equivalent to defining a temporary variable of the same type as the return value and then initializing it with the same expression following the return.

A local variable is a variable in function body.

I want to know what is the difference between temporary variable and local variable in C?

Comment: I'd say both are the same. One doesn't return a variable, but in fact, its content (value)

Comment: There are no terms such as "temporary" or "non-temporary" variable in C. There are storage durations, of which two might be appropriate here: static and automatic.  Are you asking about them?

Comment: _temporary_ is anything short of forever.  Any variable created by a non-forever process is _temporary_.  When the program ends, even the files with global scope will cease to exist.

Answer (score 2):

A local variable is local to its area i.e. it is only visible in that limited **scope**.

A temporary variable is a variable that exists only for a short period of **time**, it has nothing to do with scope.

So that's the basic difference between a local variable and a temporary variable.

In your case, you find them both similar because there is no restriction that a temporary variable cannot be a local variable. The variable which was local to your function body was returned and stored in a temporary variable so that it could be used for some purpose and then go rest.

Answer (score 1):

There is not really a difference, a local variable means that it is local to that function or a block within a function, it will cease to exist as soon as the function or the block goes out of scope, so it is by definition a temporary variable.

Comment: A variable can be local to a block within a function too.

Comment: That's well put.

Comment: ...which besides being _well put_, points out an opportunity for you to improve your answer.

Comment: @ryyker if you read it you will see that it's already done.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is the lifetime. The lifetime of a local variable starts at the beginning of the bloc in which it is declared and ends at the end of that block. The lifetime of a temporary variable ends as soon as it has been used.

Comment: "The lifetime of a temporary variable ends as soon as it has been used." Can you give an example of this in C?